# Print line if line starts with any letter of the alphabet

Tags: python

I'm trying to print all of my reptile subspecies in my python program. I have a text file with a bunch of subspecies and their DNA sequence IDs. I just want to create a dictionary of subspecies (keys) and their respective DNA sequence IDs (values). But to do that I need to first learn how to separate the two.

So I want to print all of the subspecies names only, and to ignore the sequence IDs.

So far I have

```
import re
file = open('repCleanSubs2.txt')
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('[a-zA-Z]'):
        print line
```

I believe the compiler takes the `'[a-zA-Z]'`as a string literal, rather than a search for any letter of the alphabet regardless the case sensitivity, which is what I want.

Is there some syntax that I'm missing in my `if` statement?

Thanks!

Comment: You import `re` but you never use it

Comment: Ah I see, fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`startswith` does not interpret regular expressions. use the re module you have imported to check if a string is a match:

```
if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+', line) is not None:
    print line
```

starts with: `^`

one or more matching characters: `+`

http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html

Comment: Thanks, what would the plus sign mean in this regex example?

Comment: Just another quick question, is there a way I could alphabetically sort the output in the same `if` statement?

Comment: what do you mean sort the output? re.match returns an object.

Comment: So then what's the best way of going about adding the subspecies to a dictionary? I have to find them first and I thought this would be the only way

Comment: you can add them to a list `[ ]` instead of printing directly, and then print the whole list like this `print sorted(my_list)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

file = open('repCleanSubs2.txt')
for line in file:
    match = re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', line)
    if match:
        print line, match
```

The `^` sign means match from the beginning of the line, letters between `a-z` and `A-Z`

`+` means at least one or more characters in `[a-zA-Z]` must be found

`re.findall` will return a list of all the patterns it could find in the string you supplied to it

Comment: The re.findall is just what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following lines instead of the startswith.

```
if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]", line):
       print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me:

```
import re
file = open('repCleanSubs2.txt')
for line in file:
if (re.match('[a-zA-Z]',line)):
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

without using `re`:

```
import string
with open('repCleanSubs2.txt') as c_file:
    for line in c_file:
        if any([line.startswith(c) for c in string.letters]):
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
file = open("abc.xyz")
file_content = file.read()
line = file_content.splitlines()
output_data = []

for i in line:
     if i[0] == '[a-zA-Z]':
     output_data.append(i)
     print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

**It can be done without regular expression**

```
data = open('repCleanSubs2.txt').read().splitlines() ## Read file and extract data as list

print [i for i in data if i[0].isalpha()]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.